# Excel data organized in multiple nested rows, can R read it?

Tags: r, xlsx

Please see the picture. I've started using R, and know how/that it can read files from Excel, but can it read something formatted like this?

http://www.flickr.com/photos/68814612@N05/8632809494/

(my apologies, upload was not working for me)

Comment: Yes. But it will require some regex and splitting-foo.

Comment: I figured it could. I will look into these methods, thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Without a reproducible example, I'm afraid there is very little we can do. Let's get data into R first. Have you tried reading the file using functions designed to read excel files?

Comment: That's fixed width format.  See `?read.fwf`

Comment: My favorite is the confidential notice on the data sample

Comment: Haha, yes I know. It is added automatically, even though I removed all sensitive information from the data.

Comment: @Andrie: Thanks for that input, this seems to be exactly what I need. The file originally came to me in a .xls format, can I just replace the .xls filetype with .fwf? It also seems widths is a required argument, but it's multiline and they all seem to be different sizes. How can I determine these? Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on some of what's in the comments:

If you load the file into Excel, you can save it as a fixed-width or comma-delimited text file.  Either should be easy to read into R.

The following may be obvious to you already.

(First, a question: Are you sure that you can't get the data in a format that has one set of data per line?  Is it possible that the file you're getting was generated from a different file format that is more conducive to loading the data into R?)

Whether you should start rearranging the data in R or instead manipulate the raw text depends on what comes naturally to you (or to people you have around who can help).  For me, personally, I would rearrange the text file outside of R before loading it into R.  That's what's easiest for me.  Perl is a great language for this purpose, but you could also do it with Unix shell scripts if that's accessible to you, or using a powerful editor such as Vim or Emacs.  If you have no preference, I'd suggest Perl.  If you have any significant programming experience, you'll be able to learn what you need.  On the other hand, you're already loading it into R, so maybe it would be better to process the data there.

For example, you could execute a loop that goes the text file line by line and does something like this:

```
while (still have lines to read) {
  read first header line into an vector if this is the first time through the loop
   otherwise, read it and throw it away
  read data line 1 into an vector
  read second header line into vector if this is the first time
   otherwise, read it and throw it away
  read data line 2 into an vector
  read third header line into vector if this is the first time
   otherwise, read it and throw it away
  read data line 3 into an vector
  if this is first time through, concatenate the header vectors; store as next row
    in something (a file, a matrix, a dataframe, etc.)
  concatenate the data vectors you've been saving, and store as next row in same thing
}

write out the whole 2D data structure
```

Or if the headers will never change, then you could just embed them literally into the script before the loop, and throw them out no matter what.  That will make the code cleaner.  Or read the first few lines of the file separately to get the headers, and then have a separate script to read the data and add it to the file with the headers in it.  (The headers will probably be useful in R, so I would suggest preserving them at the top of the text file.)